# Flutter app updated by only 10% of all users (Android)

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console, release-management, rollout

I own an Android app with about 300K users.

This app was initially an Android app only that I converted to flutter in order to release an iOS version as well.
When I released the first update developed using Flutter, I deployed only 5%, then updated to 10%, to be sure there was no major issue with this new version.

I then updated to deployment to 100%.

I have now released my third version of this new app based on flutter, setting a deployment of 100%, available in all countries.

But I only see about 10% of the users updating the app in the play console, after about 3 weeks.

I know flutter is not compatible with x86 phones, but those x86 represents only 1% of the Android phones. I also had to update the minSdkVersion from 19 to 20, but again this should not impact so much users.

I also read the app size could impact installations and updates, but the size was reduced using flutter.

I do not understand why my app is updated by only 10% of all users more than 3 weeks after the update. I'm seeing about 90% of my users in the play console still using the previous app version, and I double checked the deployment was set to 100% in all countries.

Thanks for any tip you can provide me.

Answer (score 0):

so there are a few reason i can point out why this is happening :

- If you are using google analytics , there is a strong possibility that the stats might be old and not yet updated (sometimes analytics run behind )
- Your target sdk version might be too low and the majority of people might be using legacy play store version and it might cause an issue ( it's a long shot , it wont matter 99.9 % of the time)
- when you switch to deployment (100%) , then play store pushes it as a normal update and devices wait for wifi to update . countries like india,china and middle east don't have a good wifi coverage .
- If u switched app from kotlin or java to flutter , there will be some delay in it getting mainstreamed by play store.

**To Avoid these issues , u can do a few things**

- Make sure to have a [version check inside app](https://pub.dev/packages/version_check) that checks for latest version and then prompts users if ***version!=latest_version && version< latest_version***.
- Send a fcm to users where ***version < latest_version*** .
- try publishing another minor update within same version (0.1.1 to 0.1.2) and check it's stats (its probably the best way to update stats).

Hope it helps , let me know.

Comment: The strange thing is that I observed 100% of users updating correctly before I switched to Flutter, and I released multiple versions using Flutter with the initial deployment set to 100%. I've the feeling the app is just not available to most of my users, so sending them a FCM or checking version inside app is not relevant.

Comment: after sending the fcm you can observe the number of sends and compare it to the number of devices you have after 10 hours so you can know how many devices are actually active